# Copy container image from one Google project to another using terraform

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform, terraform-provider-gcp, google-container-registry

I have an image in the container registry of say "Project A"  and want to copy it over to the container registry of "Project B". How do I do it using terraform ?

Comment: Why do you need to copy an image in the project? Can you simply use it and grant the permission on the container registry?

Comment: I have projects for different environments, say one each for dev, stage and prod. And as I migrate the code from one environment to the other, I want to keep a copy of the container in each project. Right now I am granting the permission to the dev container registry from stage and prod projects, but want to change that to copy instead to retain the containers for rollbacks etc.

Comment: Not sure that is the best pattern. When you go from an envitonment to another one, most of the time it's linked to GIT branches. When you push in another branch, another pipeline run, build your container and store it somewhere. It's when you store your container that you need to put it at the right place. Like that, you can rollback your code in the correct branch, the build start again and the deployment follow. Keep in mind that terraform isn't a software deployment tool, just an infra tool!

Comment: That makes sense, I'll look at using that approach. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you should, but that does not mean you can't.

**Don't**
Terraform is an excellent tool to manage *infrastructure* with; it's not great for interacting with data or application code. The line between these two can be hard to draw, especially with GCP's high-level services like AppEngine, Cloud Run, ..., but imo, where a container *registry* can be treated as infrastructure, a container *image* should be treated as data (or code), and not be managed in Terraform. Don't do it!

**But I really want to...**
Hey, who am I to judge? Maybe there's something about your particular problem that I don't know about. There's no GCP resources for copying or interacting with images, but you can interact with GCR as generic container registries. You can use the community module [`neomantra/mirror/docker`](https://registry.terraform.io/modules/neomantra/mirror/docker/latest). Its [sources](https://github.com/neomantra/terraform-docker-mirror/blob/master/main.tf) are pretty easy to read and adapt; it uses the
`docker_image` resource to pull the remote image to your local machine, followed by a well-timed [`local-exec`](https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/resources/provisioners/local-exec.html) to `docker push` the image to its destination.

Example usage:

```
module "docker-mirror-vault" {
  source        = "github.com/neomantra/terraform-docker-mirror?ref=v0.4.0"
  image_name    = "myexample"
  image_tag     = "latest"
  source_prefix = "us.gcr.io/my-one-gcp-project"
  dest_prefix   = "us.gcr.io/my-other-gcp-project"
}
```

You can optionally use the data resource [`google_container_registry_image`](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/google/latest/docs/data-sources/container_registry_image) for constructing the handles to the images in Container Registry.

**Fyi**, if you're migrating, consider migrating to Artifact Registry, as Google is deprecating the Container Registry in favor of the Artifact Registry.

Comment: Thanks Semafoor for the answer and the recommendation. I too have been thinking on the same lines was not sure where to draw the line. Another option I was looking into is using the gcloud cli ( https://cloud.google.com/container-registry/docs/managing#copying_images_to_a_new_registry)

Comment: I agree with the guidance about treating images as data and not infrastructure.  However, as I'm learning terraform with google cloud I keep encountering chicken-and-egg problems.  For example, to set up CI-CD for a Cloud Run service using terraform, I need an image before I've completed the first build.  I want to use a dummy helloworld image and then overwrite the image when the build occurs.